# What is the best practice for designing an Android application with self update content?

Tags: android

My firm has been developing a number of Android apps lately and it has become a common theme that our applications should be able to self update their content without having to download an update through Google Play. While we've come up with some solutions, I've run into quite a few limitations doing this and I wanted to get people's opinion on what the right way to go about this.

The biggest problem with updateable content is that the entire android resource loading system becomes completely unusable. Since my content is external from the android resource folders the ability to use the android standard for locale, resolution, dp, land/port etc.

It seems to be like self updating content or context external to your apk would be a very common requirement in many android apps. Has anyone come up with a better solution to this problem?